# How to migrate from Realtime to Firestore database in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am taking my app from realtime database to firestore database. So far, I have done so using EventListener which successfully worked, but when it comes to using a QuerySnapshot instead, I am at a loss.

My function is to retrieve user info from the database. It looks like this:

```
fun getUsersInfo() {


    usersDb!!.addSnapshotListener(EventListener<QuerySnapshot> { snapshot, e ->


        if (e != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
            return@EventListener
        } else {


             //retrieve documents and set name, age, etc.


        }


    })
}
```

But I am not sure how I reference the documents, as the QuerySnapshot has no get command, unlike the DocumentSnapshot

Here is the old realtime code,  that I am trying to migrate:

```
usersDb!!.addSnapshotListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String?) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("sex").value != null) {
                if (dataSnapshot.key == FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid)
                    return

                if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId!!) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yeps").hasChild(currentUId!!)) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("sex").value!!.toString() == userInterest || userInterest == "Both") {
                        var name = ""
                        var age = ""
                        var job = ""
                        var about = ""
                        //  var userSex = ""
                        var profileImageUrl = "default"

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("name").value != null)
                            name = dataSnapshot.child("name").value!!.toString()
                        //  if (dataSnapshot.child("sex").value != null)
                        //     userSex = dataSnapshot.child("sex").value!!.toString()
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("age").value != null)
                            age = dataSnapshot.child("age").value!!.toString()
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("job").value != null)
                            job = dataSnapshot.child("job").value!!.toString()
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("about").value != null)
                            about = dataSnapshot.child("about").value!!.toString()
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").value != null)
                            profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").value!!.toString()

                        val item = cardObject(dataSnapshot.key!!, name, age, about, job, profileImageUrl)

                        for (i in rowItems.indices)
                            if (rowItems[i] === item)
                                return

                        rowItems.add(item)
                        cardAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String?) {}
        override fun onChildRemoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {}

        override fun onChildMoved(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, s: String?) {}
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
    })
```

Which is basically just a check if the users are same sex and a check to not add current user to the array

Appologize if the code is hard to read, I am using firebase for the first time. Let me know if you would have done anything differently

Comment: Your code samples don't look comparable to me.  In the first, you're defining a function called `getUsersInfo`.  What is its purpose?  In the second sample, you're just showing a database listener not inside a function that just processes realtime data and populates an adapter.  What are you really trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `addSnapshotListener` in Firestore, you get a `QuerySnapshot` that contains *all documents* matching `usersDb`.

On the other hand, your code for the Realtime Database you're using `onChildAdded`, which gets called for *each individual node* matching `usersDb`.

So to get on the same level in your Firestore code, you'll need to loop over the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`. For an example of this, see the documentation on [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

```
db.collection("cities")
  .whereEqualTo("state", "CA")
  .addSnapshotListener { value, e ->
      if (e != null) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e)
          return@addSnapshotListener
      }

      val cities = ArrayList<String>()
      for (doc in value!!) {
          doc.getString("name")?.let {
              cities.add(it)
          }
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "Current cites in CA: $cities")
  }
```

In the above, the `it` variable is a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), which has methods that are similar to the `getValue()` that you know from Realtime Database.